# CustomSelect causing infinite renders for onChange function, React, TS, MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a mui element **CustomSelect** which works perfect on desktop, handleChange function from onChange console logs only once but on mobile (also in development mode) it renders 51 times then it crashes giving this error: *Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.* then it console logs onnce more.

So I'm thinking to use e.preventDefault() but I cannot use the "*event*" on onChange because it gives this error: "*Type '(e: any, newValue: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: number | null) => void'.*"

So how can I pass the "event" to CustomSelect

```
const CustomSelect = forwardRef(function CustomSelect(
      props: SelectUnstyledProps<number>,
      ref: React.ForwardedRef<any>,
   ) {
   const components: SelectUnstyledProps<number>['components'] = {
      Root: StyledButton,
      Listbox: StyledListbox,
      Popper: StyledPopper,
      ...props.components,
   };

    return <SelectUnstyled {...props} ref={ref} components={components}/>;
});
```

The jsx element:

```
<CustomSelect value={value} onChange={(e: any, newValue: any) => handleChange(e, newValue)}>
{$languageOptions.map((c, i) => (
    <StyledOption key={i} value={c.value}>
         <>
           ....
         </>
    </StyledOption>
))}
 </CustomSelect>
```

i tryed using `props: SelectUnstyledProps<number> & {event: any},` then return from the forwardRef `return <SelectUnstyled {...props} ref={ref} components={components} onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event, props.event)} />;` but I get more errors

Comment: Try using `useMemo` when creating the `components` variable

Comment: i tried on both handleChange and in forwardRef on "component" variable, didn't work, also tried using useCallback on handleChange

Comment: Can you show how have you tried this?

Comment: If you get the error `Type '(e: any, newValue: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: number | null) => void'.` that means you are trying to use arguments that do not exist. You have to remove `e: any` and only leave `newValue`, you don't need to put `any`. The type is automatic.

Comment: found that is a common bug https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33457

Answer (score 0):

I finally RESOLVED this by removing onChange from CustomSelect and put onClick on StyledOption

```
<CustomSelect value={value} >
    {$languageOptions.map((c, i) => (
        <StyledOption key={i} 
                      value={c.value} 
                      onClick={() => handleChange(c.value)}
        >
            <>
                ...     
            </>
        </StyledOption>
    ))}
</CustomSelect>


const [value, setValue] = useState(LANGUAGE)

const handleChange = (newValue: string) => {
    setValue(newValue)
    console.log(newValue) //"ro" || "en"
    if (newValue === LANGUAGE) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```